# json_extract_scalar is not extracting value from json string with single quote

Tags: json, amazon-athena, json-extract

I have an athena record with a json string as below.

```
{'is_referred': False, 'landing_page': '/account/register'}
```

I tried to extract the `landing_page` value with query below but it returns null value.

```
select 
    json_string,
    json_extract_scalar(json_string, '$.landing_page') as landing_page
from
    my_table
```

I have also tried to replace the single quote to double quote but still can't retrieve the value.

```
select 
    json_string,
    replace(json_string, '''', '"') as double_quoted_json_string
    json_extract_scalar(double_quoted_json_string, '$.landing_page') as landing_page
from
    my_table
```

Any advice, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not valid json.  Single quotes should be double quotes and boolean values should start with a lower case.

To fix that one sample you provided you will need nested replace() inside of the json_extract_scalar() function.  One replace for the single to double quote and another to fix the upper case **False**.

Here is a working example:

```
--CTE with test data
with my_table as (
    select *
    From (
            values(
                    '{''is_referred'': False, ''landing_page'': ''/account/register''}'
                )
        ) as my_table (json_string)
)
select *,
    json_extract_scalar(
        replace(replace(json_string, '''', '"'), ': False', ': false'),
        '$.landing_page'
    )
from my_table
```

Giving a result of:
[image]

That only works for this one sample.  If you have data with boolean values of **True** you would need to do another replace.

Without knowing your full data set there could be other anomalies that this would not work for.

Comment: Thank you, Tim. That's indeed the case. I overlooked the boolean string.